# Does SherlockListActivity have similar included functionality in TrackedListActivity?

Tags: android, android-widget, actionbarsherlock

I am using TrackedListActivity, but want to use SherlockListActivity instead; to ensure I have the actionbar backwards compatibility.

Did I just 'kill' TrackedListActivity functionality?

Comment: UPDATE: I'm INCREDIBLY sorry. It appears that TrackedListActivity can extend SherlockListActivity. Want to verify with the community. Again, sorry my first post was possibly not thought out.